# How to Remove Pop-up Messages from VBS App

Tags: vbscript, silent

I downloaded this vbs script that is designed to block time wasting websites such as Facebook and YouTube. It works perfectly fine but I want it to run completely silent. When the application is executed, a Wscript message comes up asking if I want to run the file, and after clicking yes another message comes up stating that websites have been blocked.

After reviewing the code, I commented out the messages stating websites blocked/unblocked which prevented them from coming up but then the websites don't get blocked. What changes need to be made to the code so that nothing pops up at all and therefore other users cannot tell an application is blocking websites.

```
'Add the list of time wasting websites here
WebsitesToBlock = Array("twitter.com", "www.youtube.com", "www.facebook.com")

If WScript.Arguments.length =0 Then
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    objShell.ShellExecute "wscript.exe", Chr(34) & WScript.ScriptFullName & Chr(34) & " RunAsAdministrator", "", "runas", 1
Else
    Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2

    Set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")    
    root = shell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%systemroot%")     
    hostFile = root & "\system32\drivers\etc\hosts"
    tempFile = hostFile & ".bak"

    blocked = 0
    towrite = false

    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set f1 = fso.OpenTextFile(hostFile, ForReading, True)
    Set f2 = fso.OpenTextFile(tempFile, ForWriting, True)

    Do Until f1.AtEndOfStream

        line = f1.Readline
        towrite = true

        For Each URL in WebsitesToBlock
            If instr(line, URL) Then
                If blocked = 0 Then 
                    If left(line, 1) = "#" Then blocked = 1 Else blocked = 2
                End If
            towrite = false
            End If
        Next    

        If towrite Then f2.WriteLine line
    Loop

    For Each URL in WebsitesToBlock
        If blocked <> 2 Then
            f2.WriteLine "127.0.0.1" & vbTab & vbTab & URL 
        End If
    Next

    fso.Copyfile tempFile, hostFile

    f1.Close
    f2.Close

    If blocked = 2 Then 
        WScript.echo "Time wasting websites have now been unblocked on this computer" 
    Else
        WScript.echo "Time wasting websites are now blocked on this computer!" 
    End If

End If
```

Comment: To get rid of the second message remove the `If blocked = 2 Then ... End If` section at the end of the script. Removing or commenting that section does not change anything about what the script does, so it's not possible that the script worked with that section and didn't work without it. The first message is most likely not from WScript but from UAC, so it cannot be removed without changing the computer's UAC configuration.